# Virtual Private Server of Windows 10 ready up application before logon

Tags: windows, boot, virtualization, vps

I do like the feature that my laptop windows 10 ready up my startup application just before login.
Features from - Use sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device and reopen my apps after an update or restart.

But when it comes to Rented Windows 10 VPS, running on virtual machine, i do not able to get it run application before login to desktop.
Same settings enabled, but it starts the application after login (restart)

So basically,
Vitual desktop doesn't behave the same way as physical version? or is there somekind of tricks, i am aware of Task Scheduler/Autologin but i don't want to set those up in hundred of rented virtual machines...